# Angular decode HTML apostrophe

Tags: angularjs

Getting a bit stuck with a quirky little Angular problem. I've got a JSON feed which converts characters like apostrophes into HTML entities - ie, & # 0 3 9;

Obviously, this isn't a great look in the page's  tag.

From the controller:

```
document.title = $scope.currentComic.title + " | " + "[Site Name]";
```

From the html page:

```
<title ng-bind-html="title"></title>
```

All help appreciated,
Dan

Comment: Example text "Fella's Choice" is being rendered as "Fella&#039;s Choice" in the page's <title> tag. That HTML-encoded character should not be there.

Comment: I dont think this is an angular problem

Comment: Ideally this wouldn't be an Angular problem - but it's the part of the system over which I've got the most access. 

As an alternative, how would I get Angular and JS working together to solve the problem?

Comment: @Dan `title` is being sanitised by Angular, which is why you're seeing HTML entities. You'll need to use [`$sce.trustAsHtml`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) to bypass this.

Comment: @miqid - working on this now. Do I need to declare $sce in the same way as ngSanitize, or are they the same thing?

Comment: @Dan include `angular-sanitize.js`, declare `ngSanitize` as a dependency in the module you intend to use `$sce` in, and use `$sce` as you would an Angular service (i.e. as a dependency injection).

Comment: @miqid - Thanks, I've got $sce working now. Didn't realise I needed to pass $sce to the controller. But even with that working, I'm still seeing the HTML entity come through.

Clarifying question - should it matter whether the HTML entity is coming all the way from JSON? It's not coming from Angular trying to sanitize inputs - it's actually part of the JSON. Will that make a difference?

Comment: @Dan AFAIK, using `$sce.trustAsHtml` on a string which is then bound using `ng-bind-html` should display all HTML entities as their visual equivalents. Can't say much about your usage with the JSON feed without more content to go off.